# chrome downloads override dangerType

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-api

I'm developing an extension which, among other things, manages downloads. Is it possible to override dangerType chrome assigns to specific download with use of chrome.downloads api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [chrome.downloads.download](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-download) method does not support a `dangerType` parameter. In general though if the site and download is a good actor there shouldn't be any issues.